# React Native FIrebase with Wix React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native-firebase, wix-react-native-navigation

Has anyone got these 2 working together?

I added react native firebase to my app and it crashes on start up.

I then tested the starter kit provided by react native firebase and once I install react native navigation the app crashes.

Using React Native 0.51, React native navigation v1.1.365 and react native firebase 3.2.2

Thanks

Comment: Android or iOS? Do you have a crash log? Without them it's not very easy to diagnose your issue

Comment: Android only. Thanks for the response but I've removed the library and gone with react native FCM instead.

Comment: I use react-native-fire-base and react navigation together.
Did you tried tu downgrade react-native-firebase to stable one?
Latest react-native-firebase often cause problems.

Comment: Yeah, me too facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

Yeah.

It's Possible.

- What I did Was first Installed Firebase and configured.
- Then I Installed Wix/react-native Navigation. Follow the steps mentioned in the Official Documentation.
         Link for the same to Install and configure is    https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-android.

  a command to install library is
  "sudo npm install --save    react-native-navigation@latest".

  Note: App crashes due to MainActivity File. Please remove unwanted code snippet. It should have following code snippet only. As shown    Below.
         In MainActivity.java it should extend 
         com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.SplashActivity instead of    ReactActivity.

This file can be located in android/app/src/main/java/com/yourproject/.

```
 import com.reactnativenavigation.controllers.SplashActivity;

 public class MainActivity extends SplashActivity {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get up and running fully with [React Native FCM](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm). Seems to be the best option if using react native navigation.